# Python most frequent sentences in large text

Tags: python

My goal is to extract the **x** most frequent sentences that include the word **y**. My solution right now works this way:

1. Extract all sentences that contains the word **y**
2. Count the most frequent words in these sentences and store them in a list
3. Extract sentences that includes **z** amount of words from the list
4. In order to get **x** sentences then I simply increase or decrease **z**

So I get the most frequent sentences by looking for the most frequent words. This method works on smaller amount of data. But will take forever on larger amount of data.

**EDIT - code**

```
# Extract all sentences from data containing the word
def getSentences(word):
  sentences = []
  for x in data_lemmatized:
    if word in x:
      sentences.append(x)
  return sentences
  
# Get the most frequent words from all the sentences
def getSentenceWords(sentences):
  cnt = Counter()
  for x in sentences:
    for y in x:
      cnt[y] += 1
      
  words = []
  for x,y in cnt.most_common(30):
    if(x not in exclude and x != ' '):
      words.append(x)
  return words
  
# Get sentences that contains as many words as possible
def countWordshelp(allSentences, words, amountWords):
  tempList = []
  
  for sentence in allSentences:
    temp = len(words[:amountWords])
    count = 0
    for word in words[:amountWords]:
      if(word in sentence):
        count += 1
      if(count == temp):
        tempList.append(sentence)
    
  return tempList
  
def countWords(allSentences, words, nrSentences):
  tempList = []
  prevList = []
  amountWords = 1

  tempList = countWords2help(allSentences, words, amountWords)

  while(len(tempList) > nrSentences):
    amountWords += 1
    newAllSentences = tempList
    prevList = tempList
    tempList = countWords2help(newAllSentences,words, amountWords)

  if(len(tempList) < nrSentences):
    return prevList[:nrSentences]

  return tempList
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  for x in terms:
    for y in x:
      allSentences = getSentences(y)
      words = getSentenceWords(allSentences)
      test = countWords2(allSentences,words,nrSentences)
      allTest.append(test)
```

**terms** will be a list of list each containing 10 words, **data_lemmatized** will be the large data in lemmatized form.

Comment: Have you produced the code? It can be fast when your code is neatly built.

Comment: I have produced the code, have edited the post so you can take a look.